# How do I make the Three.js camera look at the face of an object?

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm have a sphere made of hexagons and pentagons and I am trying to make the camera look at a particular hexagon directly - so the centre of a user's view is the hex and it is flat.

The hexagons are made using the hexasphere.js plugin (https://github.com/arscan/hexasphere.js/tree/master). I am able to extract information from a mesh object which makes up a hex. But I don't know how to take the object info and tell the camera where to go.

I have tried using the normal matrix element of the mesh and finding the euler angles - but I don't know what to then do with them.

Comment: Try `camera.lookAt( hexagon_center_vertex )`.

Comment: That makes the camera change its angle to look at the face. I want it to change its position and angle so that it is looking directly at the face and the face is flat with the screen.

Comment: You need to move the camera, too, if you want it to be directly in front of the face. Then call `lookAt()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I've found a solution. The hexasphere plugin provides the centre point of a face with `hexasphereObj.tiles[i].centrePoint` which is a point object and this has a method `project(radius, percent)` which gets the coordinates of a point at a projection from the centre of the hexasphere and through the centre of the face.

I was then able to move the camera to this projected point and have it lookAt the centre of the hexasphere.